# Chrome shows URL, when JS redirects to other page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In our application, we show a loading animation, when we use JS to redirect to another site:

`<a type="button" href="javascript:showAnimation();document.location.href='http://my.example.url.com'">Test with JS</a>`

This works well for IE and Firefox. Chrome however leaves the site, showing the target-url. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the page after your function is done, like this:

```js
function doAnimation(callback) {
    window.open(callback)
}
```

```html
<a type="button"  href="#" onclick="javascript:doAnimation('http://www.google.com.br/'); return false;">Go to google</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Still I wonder why chrome behaves differently, when this assignment is made directly in href...